# SQL Server - Trying to de-normalize my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Apologies for the title but I am trying to do stuff way above my level even for me to explain it.

Say I have a table with the variables person, foodstuff and amount:

```
 Person  food     Amount
 Mike    Butter   3
 Mike    Milk     4
 Mike    Chicken  2
 Tim     Milk     4
 John    Chicken  2
```

By joining the table with itself in the query I have managed to make a list where the food is the basis for new variables and the value is the amount. The above table would become:

```
Person  Butter Milk Chicken
Mike    3      4    2
```

The code is approximately:

```
Select 
    a.person, 
    b.amount as Butter,
    c.amount as Milk, 
    d.amount as Chicken
from PersonFoodAmount a
inner join PersonFoodAmount b on a.person = b.person
inner join PersonFoodAmount c on a.person=c.person
where b.food='Butter' 
and c.food='Milk'
and d.food='Chicken'
```

Now, this gives me Mike because he checks all boxes off. But I need to also have the partial matches:

```
Person  Butter Milk Chicken
Mike    3      4    2
Tim     NULL   4    NULL
John    NULL   Null 2
```

I have tried all kinds of joins, including full outer join but I still only get persons with a full fridge.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to use sql pivot...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Pivot for make this.

```
DECLARE @PersonStuff TABLE (Person varchar(10), Food varchar(10), Amount INT)

INSERT INTO @PersonStuff VALUES
('Mike','Butter', 3),
('Mike','Milk', 4),
('Mike','Chicken', 2),
('Tim','Milk', 4),
('John','Chicken', 2)

SELECT 
    * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM @PersonStuff ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT ( 
    AVG(Amount) 
    FOR Food IN ( [Butter],[Milk],[Chicken] ) 
) AS PivotTable
```

Result:

```
Person  Butter  Milk    Chicken
John    NULL    NULL    2
Mike    3       4       2
Tim     NULL    4       NULL
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go, thank you. But to further complicate matters, "milk" is actually several numbers that goes into the category "milk". I am trying to use  "for survey_detail_id in ( [('184','202','235','253','325','359','377') as tilfreds]" as stand in for "FOR Food IN ( [Butter]" but i get a: "The incorrect value "('184','202','235','253','325','359','377') as tilfreds" is supplied in the PIVOT operator."

Comment: You should write the values like this ( [184],[202],[235],[253],[325],[359],[377] )

Comment: But would I be able to recode the multiple numbers **AS** one variable, tilfreds (/milk)? It looks like the way you write it I would get one separate variable for each number? ("seven different foodstuffs")?

Comment: You have to write like this. But if you have dynamic variables then you need to generate and execute dynamic SQL query over this query.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest something better , conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT t.person,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.food = 'Butter' THEN t.amout END) as Butter,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.food = 'Milk' THEN t.amout END) as Milk,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.food = 'Chicken' THEN t.amout END) as Chicken
FROM PersonFoodAmount t
GROUP BY t.person
```

That way, you don't have to join the table 3 times to itself. Also, I find this writing a lot easier to read once to understand it.

Comment: Operand data type NULL is invalid for max operator.

Comment: @sagi why, or when, would one use your solution over a PIVOT?

Comment: When it's a limited amount of columns, that has constant names(As I recall, it's even faster) . I always prefer this action because new programmers tend to not understand PIVOT. @Eli

Comment: @sagi, your code works ok, sorry. My test code gives me that error

Comment: I'll agree to the latter reason, as PIVOT can be hard to read for someone who has little exposure - though with regards to the first reason which you give. Unless you resort to dynamic SQL, you'll need to make modifications to the query whenever new values are introduced.

Comment: @Eli I'm not saying you're wrong, and normally at work I'll use `PIVOT` . But -- If this is a school assignment / a one time thing / a query to test something. which is logical, because most of the question here are like this, than the rest is not important.